# Cannot push huge files with Git LFS on Gitea

Tags: git, apache, git-lfs, gitea

I installed a local Gitea server with Docker.
Now I am trying to push several data files to a repo, and the files are very big (the largest is 9.2 Gb and the second largest is 2.5Gb) so I use Git LFS (I set up Gitea accordingly).
The 2.5 Gb file uploaded nicely, but I am unable to push the last one (9.2 Gb), I have the message:
`Uploading LFS objects:  89% (8/9), 11 GB | 49 MB/s`
but than just few seconds after it restart at 5.6GB -> 11GB like an endless repetition...
I've set these variables in `/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini`:

```
post_max_size = 1000G
upload_max_filesize = 1000G
```

I also launched `GIT_TRACE=1 GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=1 git push` to check for any error message but the only relevant things I see is `< HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error [....] Fatal error: Server error: https://www....`

and I don't know what to try else...
Any ideas where the issue could be ?

Comment: Gitea is a Go program and isn't affected by PHP settings.  You should look at the logs that Gitea is producing to figure out why it's failing.

Comment: I know but it is hosted behind my apache server so I thought it could be a source of error. Here is a line in logs about when I try to push: ```2020/01/19 15:33:35 .../xorm/session_raw.go:76:queryRows() [I] [SQL] SELECT `id`, `oid`, `size`, `repository_id`, `created_unix` FROM `lfs_meta_object` WHERE `oid`=? AND `repository_id`=? LIMIT 1 []interface {}{"8cf03d9e43e6353cf0a90a7663461400703a91fbb93e83d63df058b939e388b8", 10} - took: 845.249µs```